# Typo3 10.4.4 Gridelements 10.0.0 extension not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

Hey I am pretty new to typo3 and I want to build a website.
I am running version 10.4.4 of TYPO3 with the bootstrap package installed.
I have tried to follow the guide on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/stable/

I have copied the TypoScript into my template setup, but there is no output on the frontend.
Remember I am new to this so I don't understand the TypoScript well yet.
So any ideas to what I could do?

EDIT:
I want to use GriElements so that I can create my own layouts on my page. The standard layouts are good but I need more freedom than what they offer.

I can get output on the frontend without GridElements, but when I use the extension only the content in the GridElements block wont show. If I remove the standard TypoScript from the example on the manual page for this extension i get an error saying "Oops an error occurred! Code:" and then a code that changes every time I update the page.

My TypoScript on my template looks like this:

```
page.includeCSS.1 = fileadmin/user_upload/template/css/fonts.css
page.includeCSS.theme = fileadmin/user_upload/template/css/custom-theme.scss


# plugin.tx_bootstrappackage._LOCAL_LANG.da.readmore = test (NOT WORKING)
# https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Internationalization/ManagingTranslations.html

page.meta.robots = noindex, nofollow
page.meta.robots.replace = 1
page.10.partialRootPaths.3 = fileadmin/user_upload/template/partials/ContentElements/
page.10.partialRootPaths.4 = fileadmin/user_upload/template/Partials/Page/
page.10.dataProcessing.10.levels = 3
page.includeJSFooterlibs.bootstrap_navbar = fileadmin/user_upload/template/js
page.includeJSFooterlibs.bootstrap_navbar = fileadmin/user_upload/template/js/navbar.js
lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.20 = fileadmin/user_upload/template/partials/ContentElements/
lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.20 = fileadmin/user_upload/template/Partials/ContentElements/



lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup {
  // stdWrap functions being applied to each element

  columns {
    default {
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
        # You can use registers to i.e. provide different image settings for each column
        # 10 = LOAD_REGISTER
        20 =< tt_content

        # And you can reset the register later on
        # 30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
      }
    }
  }

  # if you want to provide your own templating, just insert a cObject here
  # this will prevent the collected content from being rendered directly
  # i.e. cObject = TEMPLATE or cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE will be available from the core
  # the content will be available via fieldnames like
  # tx_gridelements_view_columns (an array containing each column)
  # or tx_gridelements_view_children (an array containing each child)
  # tx_gridelements_view_column_123 (123 is the number of the column)
  # or tx_gridelements_view_child_123 (123 is the UID of the child)

}

lib.tt_content.shortcut.pages = COA
lib.tt_content.shortcut.pages {
  10 = USER
  10 {
    userFunc = tx_gridelements_view->user_getTreeList
  }
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      pidInList.data = register:pidInList
      where = colPos >= 0
      orderBy = colPos,sorting
      orderBy.dataWrap = FIND_IN_SET(pid,'{register:pidInList}'),|
    }
  }
}

tt_content.shortcut.5 = LOAD_REGISTER
tt_content.shortcut.5 {
  tt_content_shortcut_recursive.field = recursive
}

tt_content.shortcut.20 {
  0 {
    tables := addToList(pages)
    conf.pages < lib.tt_content.shortcut.pages
  }
  1 {
    tables := addToList(pages)
    conf.pages < lib.tt_content.shortcut.pages
  }
}

tt_content.gridelements_pi1 >
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 = COA
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
  #10 =< lib.stdheader
  20 = COA
  20 {
    10 = USER
    10 {
      userFunc = tx_gridelements_view->main
      setup {
        default < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The statics i included is:

```
Bootstrap Package: Full Pacakage (bootstrap_package)
Bootstrap Package: Bootstrap 4.x (SCSS) (bootstrap_package)
XML Sitemap (seo)
Gridelements w/DataProssing (recommended) (gridelements)
Gallery (bm_image_gallery)
```

EDIT2:
New TypoScript with DataProcessing

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup {
  templateName.field = tx_gridelements_backend_layout
  templateName.ifEmpty = GridElement
  layoutRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Partials/
  }
  templateRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/
  }
  dataProcessing {
    10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
    10 {
      default {
        as = children
        # Default options of the grid children processor
        # Change them according to the needs of your layout
        # Read more about it in the TypoScript section of the manual
        # options {
          # sortingDirection = ASC
          # sortingField = sorting
          # recursive = 0
          # resolveFlexFormData = 1
          # resolveBackendLayout = 1
          # respectColumns = 1
          # respectRows = 1
        # }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My includes:

```
Fluid Contetn Elements (fluid_styled_content)
Fluid Contetn Elements CSS (fluid_styled_content)
Bootstrap Package: Full Pacakage (bootstrap_package)
Bootstrap Package: Bootstrap 4.x (SCSS) (bootstrap_package)
XML Sitemap (seo)
Gridelements w/DataProssing (recommended) (gridelements)
Gallery (bm_image_gallery)
```

The error I get:

```
Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->3" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/3.html). The following paths were checked: /httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/, /httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

Comment: You added the static template `Gridelements w/DataProssing` but your TypoScript is the code of the other static template of gridelements. So actually you use both static templates - not sure if you made changes to the copied code. The kind of implementation differs for both, so you have to make a decision which one to use.

Comment: As explanation: `Gridelements w/DataProssing` is rendering the content with fluid-templates while the other (and older) template is building it exclusively in TypoScript. The age can be seen in the code above already because `lib.stdheader` was removed from TYPO3. Nevertheless using that template without `lib.stdheader` is possible.

Comment: From `lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup` is copied directly from the manual and `lib.stdheader` is commented out also in the manual.

Comment: As I said in my answer: You forgot to include the static template of fluid_styled_content before gridelements

Comment: You're just using two different templates, no matter if from the manual or directly from the TypoScript-files of the extension. The manual might be outdated and never include the description of the newer TypoScript-template. Basically you've to understand that you've to decide for one definition / kind of usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
I installed an extension that is called "Grids for bootstrap" included it in the template and it worked.

Thnaks for all the help you guys gave!

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed to include the static template of gridelemnts. To do so edit your TS-Root-Template, select in the dropdown at the top "Info/Modify", hit the button "Edit the whole template record", go to tab "Includes" and select gridelements static setup in the Multiselect box on the right.

Comment: I did remember to include the static template of gridelemnts, so that is sadly not the problem

Comment: So how does your TypoScript Setup looks like?

Comment: As this can have many reasons and could become a longer trip I advice to ask the question in TYPO3's Slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information:

- Which static templates have you included at all? Maybe you forgot to include fluid_styled_content?
- How does your Typoscript/Flexform setup look like?
- For what do you need gridelements?

EDIT: bootstrap_package did not very well together with gridelements in the past. Maybe you should first try to install Benjamin Knott's extension [autogrids](https://github.com/benjaminkott/autogrids) (see this issue on [github](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/619) for more information)

EDIT 2: Try this Typoscript, it just wraps a section around all elements but maybe you will then see your content in the frontend:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    section < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    section {
        wrap >
        dataWrap = <section id="c{field:uid}">|</section>
    }
}
```

Comment: The part after your edit can be considered as answer. The first part alone is no answer according to rules here on Stack Overflow. Feel welcome to provide a full setup with all involved extensions, it will be some work, but grant you many upvotes too probably and show wizzi to succeed. The document [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might help you.

Comment: I do not have a fluid_styled_content in my Include static list on my template. is that another extension i need to add to my page then?

Comment: It is a sysext so you don't need to install it. Check if it's enabled in the extension manager.

Comment: okay but if i include that every content element just says Oops, an error occurred! Code:
unless i put it at the top before the bootstrap package adn then it wont show the gridelements anyway

Comment: Yes I think you have to include it before bootstrap_package. If still nothing is rendered the problem should be in your Typoscript setup. Another question: Are the gridelements displayed right in the backend?

Comment: For general debug purposes your TYPO3 should be in debug mode and you should set config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0 in your Typoscript. You will then get exact error messages and not only "oops an error occured"

Comment: Yes they are displayed right in the backend. do i also need to include the fluid content elements css?
If it is a problem with my Typoscript setup what could then be the error?

Comment: usage of the css is advisable and never producing any errors on the level where you've problems in the moment.

Comment: The Typoscript in your first post is that of the static template without dataprocessing. I would say you should remove it and include the standard template instead. I also think you don't need that one with DataProcessing. Also please see my answer again, I will soon edit some lines of Typoscript to test which might work for you.

Comment: Ah okay so i have been using the wrong TypoScript. The gridelement thet i can include without the DataProcessing is depricated so it would be best to use the other one. For that the manual also has some TypoScript i am putting the new Typoscript in an update in my first comment now. Sadly that does not work. it gives me an error.

Comment: I don't know if it matters which of both templates you use. But you definitely should not copy the Typoscript from the documentation. Just include the static template instead. My Typoscript works for me so maybe the problem here really is bootstrap_package and you should use autogrids extension.

Comment: Autogrids has not been updated and if i read the issues right it does not work for typo3 10x versions. It does not work witout the TypoScript either. For the error with gridelements it says:
Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->3" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/3.html).

Comment: I sadly still get the error i have posted in my top post even whit the TS you have written:(

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is coming from your fluid code for gridelemnts, you didn't use the right syntax maybe.